# Adding new peer in existing organization in hyperledger fabric v1.3 causing new peer to failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to add a new peer into the existing organization `org1.example.com`

I followed the steps mentioned in this tutorial 
https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217

I installed the chaincode on existing network before adding a new peer

I then changed the count of peers of `org1.example.com` from 2 to 3. Then I executed the following command:

```
cryptogen extend --input="crypto-config" --config=crypto-config.yaml
```

The output of this command was nothing.

Then I bootstrap the new peer with the following `docker-compose` configuration file:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  peer2.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:


services:

  couchdb4:
      container_name: couchdb4
      image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
      # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
      # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
      environment:
        - COUCHDB_USER=
        - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
      # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
      # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
      ports:
        - "5988:5984"
      networks:
        - byfn


  peer2.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer2.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer2.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb4:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer2.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 11051:7051
      - 11053:7053
    networks:
      - byfn
```

But the logs keep showing:

```
peer2.org1.example.com    | 2018-11-15 17:51:38.952 UTC [gossip/gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 5bf Message GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer0.org2.example.com:7051" pki_id:"\316\347\246\2250\0171\025\221\"=\266|V\037$ \265\213\037\220z`\303\351\257\001\017\216\370J>" > timestamp:<inc_num:1542303654280601328 seq_num:736 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes isn't valid
peer2.org1.example.com    | 2018-11-15 17:51:38.952 UTC [gossip/gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 5c0 Message GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer0.org2.example.com:7051" pki_id:"\316\347\246\2250\0171\025\221\"=\266|V\037$ \265\213\037\220z`\303\351\257\001\017\216\370J>" > timestamp:<inc_num:1542303654280601328 seq_num:736 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes isn't valid
peer2.org1.example.com    | 2018-11-15 17:51:39.123 UTC [gossip/gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 5c1 Message GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer1.org2.example.com:7051" pki_id:"\262>\03566\350\330~\374\215(#\323\375\331\317\234%,\215-\024\316O\327v}\005\263\374\\\224" > timestamp:<inc_num:1542303654503183827 seq_num:738 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes isn't valid
peer2.org1.example.com    | 2018-11-15 17:51:39.124 UTC [gossip/gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 5c2 Message GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer1.org2.example.com:7051" pki_id:"\262>\03566\350\330~\374\215(#\323\375\331\317\234%,\215-\024\316O\327v}\005\263\374\\\224" > timestamp:<inc_num:1542303654503183827 seq_num:738 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes isn't valid
peer2.org1.example.com    | 2018-11-15 17:51:40.103 UTC [peer/gossip/mcs] Verify -> ERRO 5c3 Failed getting validated identity from peer identity [Peer Identity [0a 07 4f 72 67 32 4d 53 50 12 a6 06 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 43 4a 7a 43 43 41 63 36 67 41 77 49 42 41 67 49 51 46 54 76 55 43 2b 6a 78 6a 32 50 4e 63 41 48 33 45 61 45 68 4d 7a 41 4b 42 67 67 71 68 6b 6a 4f 50 51 51 44 41 6a 42 7a 4d 51 73 77 0a 43 51 59 44 56 51 51 47 45 77 4a 56 55 7a 45 54 4d 42 45 47 41 31 55 45 43 42 4d 4b 51 32 46 73 61 57 5a 76 63 6d 35 70 59 54 45 57 4d 42 51 47 41 31 55 45 42 78 4d 4e 55 32 46 75 49 45 5a 79 0a 59 57 35 6a 61 58 4e 6a 62 7a 45 5a 4d 42 63 47 41 31 55 45 43 68 4d 51 62 33 4a 6e 4d 69 35 6c 65 47 46 74 63 47 78 6c 4c 6d 4e 76 62 54 45 63 4d 42 6f 47 41 31 55 45 41 78 4d 54 59 32 45 75 0a 62 33 4a 6e 4d 69 35 6c 65 47 46 74 63 47 78 6c 4c 6d 4e 76 62 54 41 65 46 77 30 78 4f 44 45 78 4d 54 55 78 4e 7a 4d 32 4d 44 42 61 46 77 30 79 4f 44 45 78 4d 54 49 78 4e 7a 4d 32 4d 44 42 61 0a 4d 47 6f 78 43 7a 41 4a 42 67 4e 56 42 41 59 54 41 6c 56 54 4d 52 4d 77 45 51 59 44 56 51 51 49 45 77 70 44 59 57 78 70 5a 6d 39 79 62 6d 6c 68 4d 52 59 77 46 41 59 44 56 51 51 48 45 77 31 54 0a 59 57 34 67 52 6e 4a 68 62 6d 4e 70 63 32 4e 76 4d 51 30 77 43 77 59 44 56 51 51 4c 45 77 52 77 5a 57 56 79 4d 52 38 77 48 51 59 44 56 51 51 44 45 78 5a 77 5a 57 56 79 4d 53 35 76 63 6d 63 79 0a 4c 6d 56 34 59 57 31 77 62 47 55 75 59 32 39 74 4d 46 6b 77 45 77 59 48 4b 6f 5a 49 7a 6a 30 43 41 51 59 49 4b 6f 5a 49 7a 6a 30 44 41 51 63 44 51 67 41 45 47 4d 4f 54 72 4b 35 48 5a 30 66 48 0a 43 6a 71 68 67 67 59 4e 30 6a 7a 39 5a 76 70 56 47 47 56 76 57 65 55 39 6b 33 4a 53 51 54 75 39 6f 6a 53 6d 6e 6e 44 30 4d 4d 55 77 50 4c 2b 4a 69 56 77 37 6d 55 30 51 71 42 44 64 4f 61 67 72 0a 69 78 48 39 54 47 78 37 4e 71 4e 4e 4d 45 73 77 44 67 59 44 56 52 30 50 41 51 48 2f 42 41 51 44 41 67 65 41 4d 41 77 47 41 31 55 64 45 77 45 42 2f 77 51 43 4d 41 41 77 4b 77 59 44 56 52 30 6a 0a 42 43 51 77 49 6f 41 67 50 75 6c 39 4e 37 6a 57 34 39 68 68 32 70 70 50 65 6f 52 54 2f 48 52 6b 4b 32 50 47 62 77 73 4b 35 58 41 6f 4f 57 45 4d 2b 44 6f 77 43 67 59 49 4b 6f 5a 49 7a 6a 30 45 0a 41 77 49 44 52 77 41 77 52 41 49 67 66 69 35 58 4a 58 4a 55 57 47 73 4b 5a 77 62 70 63 63 75 52 50 66 6c 31 4b 48 61 4b 44 42 30 69 2f 49 39 30 47 61 4d 72 55 6d 41 43 49 44 63 45 72 52 55 6e 0a 39 48 4c 66 73 45 55 6f 30 31 70 49 44 70 76 31 37 49 68 6f 43 4f 5a 6b 33 69 57 72 34 68 48 36 4a 78 79 30 0a 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 45 4e 44 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a] cannot be validated. No MSP found able to do that.]
peer2.org1.example.com    | 2018-11-15 17:51:40.104 UTC [gossip/gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 5c4 Failed validating identity message: Peer Identity [0a 07 4f 72 67 32 4d 53 50 12 a6 06 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 43 4a 7a 43 43 41 63 36 67 41 77 49 42 41 67 49 51 46 54 76 55 43 2b 6a 78 6a 32 50 4e 63 41 48 33 45 61 45 68 4d 7a 41 4b 42 67 67 71 68 6b 6a 4f 50 51 51 44 41 6a 42 7a 4d 51 73 77 0a 43 51 59 44 56 51 51 47 45 77 4a 56 55 7a 45 54 4d 42 45 47 41 31 55 45 43 42 4d 4b 51 32 46 73 61 57 5a 76 63 6d 35 70 59 54 45 57 4d 42 51 47 41 31 55 45 42 78 4d 4e 55 32 46 75 49 45 5a 79 0a 59 57 35 6a 61 58 4e 6a 62 7a 45 5a 4d 42 63 47 41 31 55 45 43 68 4d 51 62 33 4a 6e 4d 69 35 6c 65 47 46 74 63 47 78 6c 4c 6d 4e 76 62 54 45 63 4d 42 6f 47 41 31 55 45 41 78 4d 54 59 32 45 75 0a 62 33 4a 6e 4d 69 35 6c 65 47 46 74 63 47 78 6c 4c 6d 4e 76 62 54 41 65 46 77 30 78 4f 44 45 78 4d 54 55 78 4e 7a 4d 32 4d 44 42 61 46 77 30 79 4f 44 45 78 4d 54 49 78 4e 7a 4d 32 4d 44 42 61 0a 4d 47 6f 78 43 7a 41 4a 42 67 4e 56 42 41 59 54 41 6c 56 54 4d 52 4d 77 45 51 59 44 56 51 51 49 45 77 70 44 59 57 78 70 5a 6d 39 79 62 6d 6c 68 4d 52 59 77 46 41 59 44 56 51 51 48 45 77 31 54 0a 59 57 34 67 52 6e 4a 68 62 6d 4e 70 63 32 4e 76 4d 51 30 77 43 77 59 44 56 51 51 4c 45 77 52 77 5a 57 56 79 4d 52 38 77 48 51 59 44 56 51 51 44 45 78 5a 77 5a 57 56 79 4d 53 35 76 63 6d 63 79 0a 4c 6d 56 34 59 57 31 77 62 47 55 75 59 32 39 74 4d 46 6b 77 45 77 59 48 4b 6f 5a 49 7a 6a 30 43 41 51 59 49 4b 6f 5a 49 7a 6a 30 44 41 51 63 44 51 67 41 45 47 4d 4f 54 72 4b 35 48 5a 30 66 48 0a 43 6a 71 68 67 67 59 4e 30 6a 7a 39 5a 76 70 56 47 47 56 76 57 65 55 39 6b 33 4a 53 51 54 75 39 6f 6a 53 6d 6e 6e 44 30 4d 4d 55 77 50 4c 2b 4a 69 56 77 37 6d 55 30 51 71 42 44 64 4f 61 67 72 0a 69 78 48 39 54 47 78 37 4e 71 4e 4e 4d 45 73 77 44 67 59 44 56 52 30 50 41 51 48 2f 42 41 51 44 41 67 65 41 4d 41 77 47 41 31 55 64 45 77 45 42 2f 77 51 43 4d 41 41 77 4b 77 59 44 56 52 30 6a 0a 42 43 51 77 49 6f 41 67 50 75 6c 39 4e 37 6a 57 34 39 68 68 32 70 70 50 65 6f 52 54 2f 48 52 6b 4b 32 50 47 62 77 73 4b 35 58 41 6f 4f 57 45 4d 2b 44 6f 77 43 67 59 49 4b 6f 5a 49 7a 6a 30 45 0a 41 77 49 44 52 77 41 77 52 41 49 67 66 69 35 58 4a 58 4a 55 57 47 73 4b 5a 77 62 70 63 63 75 52 50 66 6c 31 4b 48 61 4b 44 42 30 69 2f 49 39 30 47 61 4d 72 55 6d 41 43 49 44 63 45 72 52 55 6e 0a 39 48 4c 66 73 45 55 6f 30 31 70 49 44 70 76 31 37 49 68 6f 43 4f 5a 6b 33 69 57 72 34 68 48 36 4a 78 79 30 0a 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 45 4e 44 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a] cannot be validated. No MSP found able to do that.
peer2.org1.example.com    | Failed verifying message
peer2.org1.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*certStore).validateIdentityMsg
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/certstore.go:103
peer2.org1.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*certStore).handleMessage
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/certstore.go:75
peer2.org1.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*gossipServiceImpl).handleMessage
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go:403
peer2.org1.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*gossipServiceImpl).acceptMessages
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go:330
peer2.org1.example.com    | runtime.goexit
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
peer2.org1.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*certStore).handleMessage
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/certstore.go:76
peer2.org1.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*gossipServiceImpl).handleMessage
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go:403
peer2.org1.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*gossipServiceImpl).acceptMessages
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go:330
peer2.org1.example.com    | runtime.goexit
peer2.org1.example.com    |     /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
```

I am using Hyperledger Fabric v1.3
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed after new peer joined the channel. The error messages were not really helpful.